# Pytorch Expected more than 1 value per channel when training when using BatchNorm

Tags: python, pytorch, batch-normalization

I've written this code:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, dataloader

inputDim = 10
n = 1000
X = np.random.rand(n,inputDim)
y = np.random.rand(0,2,n)

tensor_x = torch.Tensor(X)
tensor_y = torch.Tensor(y)
Xy = (tensor_x, tensor_y)
XyLoader = dataloader.DataLoader(Xy, batch_size = 16, shuffle = True, drop_last = True)

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
  torch.nn.Linear(inputDim, 200),
  torch.nn.ReLU(),
  torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=200),
  torch.nn.Linear(200,100),
  torch.nn.Tanh(),
  torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=100),
  torch.nn.Linear(100,1),
  torch.nn.Sigmoid()
)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr= 0.001)
loss_fn = torch.nn.BCELoss()

nepochs = 1000
for epochs in range(nepochs):
  for X,y in XyLoader:
    batch_size = X.shape[0]
    y_hat = model(X.view(batch_size,-1))
    loss = loss_fn(y_hat, y)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()


with torch.no_grad():
  xt = torch.tensor(np.random.rand(1,inputDim))
  y2 = model(xt.float())
  print(y2.detach().numpy()[0][0])
```

What am I doing wrong with torch.nn.BatchNorm1d ?
If I run the code without the two line with everything goes "ok" what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, PyTorch was simply complaining about the shape of the input to `nn.BatchNorm1d`, where the input is expected to have a shape of `(B, C, L)`. `C` is the embedding dimension and `L` is the length/timesteps of the input sequence. Usually, `1d` in PyTorch is referring to a sequence, e.g. a tokenized sentence, of which each token (`L` in total) is represented as a `C` dimensional vector and stacked over dim 1. To fix the error, you can do

```
tensor_x = torch.as_tensor(X).unsqueeze(1)  # use as_tensor to avoid unnecessary data copy
tensor_y = torch.as_tensor(y)
```

The full modified code:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

inputDim = 10
n = 1000
X = np.random.rand(n, inputDim)
y = np.random.rand(0, 2, n)

tensor_x = torch.as_tensor(X).unsqueeze(1)
tensor_y = torch.as_tensor(y)
Xy = (tensor_x, tensor_y)
XyLoader = DataLoader(Xy, batch_size = 16, shuffle = True, drop_last = True)

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
  torch.nn.Linear(inputDim, 200),
  torch.nn.ReLU(),
  torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=1),
  torch.nn.Linear(200, 100),
  torch.nn.Tanh(),
  torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=1),
  torch.nn.Linear(100,1),
  torch.nn.Sigmoid()
)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr= 0.001)
loss_fn = torch.nn.BCELoss()

nepochs = 1000
for epochs in range(nepochs):
    for X, y in XyLoader:
        batch_size = X.shape[0]
        y_hat = model(X.view(batch_size,-1))
        loss = loss_fn(y_hat, y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()


with torch.no_grad():
    xt = torch.as_tensor(np.random.rand(1, inputDim), dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(1)
    y2 = model(xt.float())
    print(y2.detach().numpy()[0][0])
```

Comment: Thanks but the error is still there

Comment: I see what you meant. It appears that the part of model definition also needs to be modified. I just updated my answer.